# Anti-Matter Strings?

Tags: string-theory, antimatter

If particles can be either matter or anti-matter, and particles are (supposedly) made up of strings, is it possible so that those strings and have anti-matter or matter properties or is it another variable affecting the matter or anti-matter properties?

Comment: What is "pro-matter"?

Comment: Normal matter, the opposite of anti-matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, in bosonic string theory, particle states arise as excitations of the string. Specifically, in light-cone quantisation, we can expand the string embedding as,

$$X^i (\tau,\sigma) = x^i + \frac{p^i}{p^+}\tau + i\sqrt{2\alpha'} \sum_{n \neq 0} \frac{1}{n}\alpha^i_n e^{-\pi inc\tau/\ell} \cos \frac{n\pi \sigma}{\ell}$$

for the open string. In this sector, we can define a general state from the modes, namely,

$$|N; k\rangle = \prod_{i= 2}^{D-1} \prod_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{(\alpha^i_n)^{N_{in}}}{(n^{N_{in}} N_{in})!} |0;k\rangle$$

which is labelled by momentum $k$ and occupation numbers $N_{in}$ for each mode $(i,n)$. If $\mathcal H_n$ denotes the $n$-string Hilbert space, then the full Hilbert space of the open string is,

$$\mathcal H = |\mathrm{vacuum} \rangle \oplus \mathcal H_1 \oplus \mathcal H_2 \oplus \dots$$

Considering different boundary conditions for the string gives rise to other sectors, and the super-string incorporates fermions as well as bosons. These states arise from excitations analogously, so any matter in this framework always arises from the fundamental string - we do not consider the string itself to be, as you proposed, anti-matter, in order to incorporate anti-matter.

Answer (score 2):

Particles are not "made up of strings" in string theory. The quantum states of the string (often called "excitations" or "modes") correspond to particle states. There is only *one type of fundamental string*, it is not the case that there would be "different" strings for matter or anti-matter - different states of the string simply can correspond to "matter" or "anti-matter", at least in the sense that some of these states behave like the antiparticles of other states.

However, it is difficult to apply the notions of "matter" or "anti-matter" to this because the "simple" string theories in flat ten dimensions do not reproduce a theory that resembles the Standard Model or "matter". Building stringy models that actually produce theories close to the Standard Model and containing "matter" roughly behaving as we are used to is possible, but not entirely straightforward.